# How to SELECT from multiple tables in Django ORM?

Tags: sql, django, select, orm

I have two tables, `oneup_backend_design` and Django's default `auth_user`.
First table have following columns (simplified): `human_readable_id`, `manager`, `worker`. Worker column contains a `username` from `auth_user`.

So I want to get `human_readable_id` plus `first_name` and `last_name` of worker associated with `username` in one query. In raw SQL it would look like this:

```sql
SELECT d.human_readable_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM oneup_backend_design as d, auth_user as u
WHERE d.worker = u.username;
```

I've tried hard reading the docs and Django ORM cookbook, but did not found anything. It's such a simple query, I should be missing something. How one can make it with single database hit?

UPD: `models.py`:

```
class Design(models.Model):
    human_readable_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=id_generator, db_index=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    worker = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
```

Comment: Do you have a `ForeignKey` from `worker` to `User`? If that is not the case, then this will be *painful*.

Comment: please add `models.py` content to question

Comment: Furthermore note that in Django, you should not think about *tables*, but about *models*. The idea of an ORM is that you do not care much about the tables, and queries, but how you represent data, and fetch data effectively.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: huh, no. I don't have `ForeignKey` from `worker` to `User`. If it's such a pain, it's probably more easier to just pass raw SQL query to database? I don't want to pollute `models.py` with Django service logic (auth system and all that stuff), it would be hard to maintain.

Comment: @ehsanahmadi: updated the question

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: and yes, I understand the purpose of ORM; my intention is to minimize DB hits. I could easily query first `Design` model for data and then match `worker` field with auth table, but there will be more than one DB hit behind the scenes. It enrages me :)

Comment: @Pantone887: I don't get why you are "polluting" `models.py` with this. It is better to use foreign keys, since these guarantee referential integrity, on most databases make indexes (to do fast querying), etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly advise to turn `worker` into a `ForeignKey`, for example referring to the `username` field of the `User` model:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Design(models.Model):
    human_readable_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, default=id_generator, db_index=True)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    worker = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        to_field='username'
    )
```

That means that `worker_id` will be a `VARCHAR` field with a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint to the `username` column of the `auth_user` table, and it will have an index, which enables fast joining. Furthermore it thus guarantees referential integrity: if the worker is not `NULL` it refers to a valid `username` of an `auth_user` object.

Then we can query with:

```
Design.objects.select_related('worker')
```

You can make use of [**`.only()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only) to narrow the columns fetched, but unless these contain large amounts of data, it is better to include these.

You can also fetch values from a related model with `.annotate(..)`:

```
from django.db.models import F

Design.objects.annotate(
    first_name=F('worker__first_name'),
    last_name=F('worker__last_name')
)
```

Here the `Design` objects from *this* queryset will have two extra attributes: `.first_name` and `.last_name`.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your model is `BackendDesign` and you have `ForeignKey` worker to `User` then:

```
BackendDesign.objects.select_related(
    'worker',
).only(
    'human_readable_id',
    'worker__first_name',
    'worker__last_name',
)
```

If this won't help please read about `extra()` in django docs
[Django docs extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#extra)
I'm new here but hope that will help

Comment: Thanks Przemysław, but unfortunately `User` is default Django `auth_user` table.

Comment: I just read that `extra()` will be deprecated so try ```BackendDesign.objects.raw('SELECT d.human_readable_id, u.first_name, u.last_name
FROM oneup_backend_design as d, auth_user as u
WHERE d.worker = u.username')```